# How can I repeat this program by responding Yes or No?

Tags: java, loops

HERE ARE MY CODES

I TRIED THE DO WHILE METHOD BUT IT DIDNT WORK AS WELL:

Should I do Case break or stick to do while method?

this is the main code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Console;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    int choice;
    int time;
    Console cons = System.console();
    if (cons==null)
    {

        System.out.println("");
        return;
    }
```

Im starting do while here but it wont work

```
    name = cons.readLine("Enter your Name: ");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("\nMenu");
    System.out.println("\n[1] Network Engineer\n[2] Software Engineer\n[3] Full Stack Developer\n[4] Technical Support");
    
    
    System.out.print("\nEnter your job(Choose a number from the menu): ");
    choice = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter no. of hours present at work: " );
    time = scn.nextInt();
    
    
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        int gsalary = 1200*time;
        int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
        
        cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
        System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 1200 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
        System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
    }
    
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        int gsalary = 800*time;
        int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
        
        cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
        System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 800 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
        System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
    }
    
    if (choice == 3)
    {
        int gsalary = 600*time;
        int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
        
        cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
        System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 600 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
        System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
    }
    
    if (choice == 4)
    {
        int gsalary = 500*time;
        int nsalary = gsalary - (gsalary * 12 / 100);
        
        cons.printf("\nHello %s!\n", name);
        System.out.println("Your job salary as a Network Engineer is 500 per hour.");
        System.out.println("Your gross salary for this week is "+gsalary+".");
        System.out.println("Your net salary for this weeks is "+nsalary+".");
    }
}
```

}Or may be Im just mistaken by those brackets can you help me determine whats the problem is?
I am new in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the `Main()` method again using an `Intent` or you could just try calling `Main()` without using `Intent` first to save some line space...